# Countif query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to run a query that calculate with a countif function but I am having trouble with it. I have used the count and the iif functions in the builder but I think something weird is going on. I am trying to count the number of times a certain value occurs in a column so I do not want a specific value to equal to if that's possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more details including the current query and what's weird.

Comment: Ok well I have a column called concatenate and is this column there are 2545 rows and I want to know how many times each specific concatenate value is in the column.

Comment: there are too many different concatenate values to make the if function equal to each individual value. I guess the best way to say it is if you were excel you would use the countif(the entire column, then the first cell in the column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of times a value appears you can use something like.
If you want to know how many times each value appears just omit the WHERE clause (without a sample of data I've used a table in the database I'm working on).

```
SELECT      ProcessID,
            COUNT(ProcessID)
FROM        tbl_PrimaryData_Step1
WHERE       ProcessID = 4
GROUP BY    ProcessID
```

if you need just the value you can use:

```
SELECT      COUNT(ProcessID)
FROM        tbl_PrimaryData_Step1
WHERE       ProcessID = 4
GROUP BY    ProcessID
```

Another way is:

```
SELECT DCOUNT("ProcessID","tbl_PrimaryData_Step1","ProcessID = 4")
```

**Edit:**
In reply to your comment on your original post this SQL will give the result you're after:

```
SELECT      Concatenate,
            COUNT(Concatenate)
FROM        MyTable
GROUP BY    Concatenate
```

Comment: I cant have the where option. I have too many different values I want to count.

Comment: Remove the WHERE option and it will give you all values.

Comment: Oh wait so your saying I can just put that in a query without the where option and it will count every value?

Comment: Gotcha sorry I just saw that

Comment: You sir are a genius thank you so much worked perfectly!